# android String numberformatexception

Tags: java, android, string

i try to split String array and show rundom values in this array.i wrote function witch can split String

```
public int Cal(String ab) {

    String[] arr=ab.split(":");
    int av=(Integer.parseInt(arr[0])*60 +  Integer.parseInt(arr[1]))*1000;



    return av;
}
```

and i call this function like this

```
String[] st =  {"00:49 ","00:49","02:17","03:26","03:55", "04:26", "05:25" };



                Random random = new Random();
                String index = st[random.nextInt(st.length)];
                Log.e("randommmmmmmmmmmm", String.valueOf(Cal(index)));
```

i have numberformatexception  exception. i have not idea what i am doing wrong

Comment: Integer.parseInt throws numberformatexception, so either arr[0] or arr[1] is not a number :)

Comment: arr[1] is '49 ' <- space

Comment: what is a solution.i want to split string.for example if i have  02:17 i want to recive 2* 60 +17

Comment: Simply use index.trim()

Comment: or just remove the whitespace from "00:49 ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Trim() method like below,

```
public int Cal(String ab) 
{
    String[] arr=ab.split(":");
    int av = ( Integer.parseInt(arr[0].trim())*60 +  Integer.parseInt(arr[1].trim()))*1000;
    return av;
}
```

`trim()` will remove spaces. Whenever you are trying to convert numeric string to number ( i.e. "11 " ), you should always remember to use `trim()` to avoid `NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 0):

It means you are passing invalid number to parseInt method. The parseInt method of Integer class expects a valid string representation of a number

Answer (score 0):

Your String array first element is having the **space** at the last --->> "00:49 "

```
 String[] arr=ab.split(":");
 Integer.parseInt(arr[1])  --------->>> This Leads to NumberFormatException
```

So Try Trimming the data before use..

```
int av=(Integer.parseInt(arr[0].trim())*60 +  Integer.parseInt(arr[1]).trim())*1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code as below.

```
public int Cal(String ab) {

    String[] arr=ab.split(":");
    int av=(Integer.parseInt(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]))*60 +  Integer.parseInt(arr[1]))*1000;



    return av;
}
```